# Rails Searchkick BulkReindexJob for 100000 rows of records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick

```
books = location.books
        # TODO: Move into a method
Searchkick::BulkReindexJob.perform_later(
        class_name: "Book",
        record_ids: books.map(&:id),
        index_name: Book.search_index.name,
        method_name: nil

)
```

Now the the books has more than 100,000,000 rows.

And it occurs Data Too Long issue on mysql.

Can we split the records?

Comment: Is this about elasticsearch? If not, I recommend you use it to store your data.That's not a lot of data.

Comment: This is not solution.  Cna we only send location id?